# Can you help me with this btw I'm just a beginner

Tags: python

so they aren't anything special that I would ask I just wanna ask that are they any alternative for input because input only accepts str and if I change the type like for example

```py
float(input(enter any number here:))
```

if the user input other thing that isn't float it would be an error but what I want is a message to pop-up and tell the user to only enter float if it detects that anything that the user type isn't float.
ps. sorry for bad grammar I'm not a native speaker and I'm just pretty much new to the programming community I would be very appreciated if you help me thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll get more help if you included the code you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

you can use try and except to catch an error and use a while loop to get input again

```py
while True:
   try:
      a = float(input("enter any number here:"))
      break
   except:
      print("Error! Please enter Valid Float NUmber")
```

Comment: Thank you very much I don't even know that there are except, try in python I just realize it after saw it in the book.